# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, site-statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Cross Validated breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 24         18
Users destroyed                                  33          0
Users deleted                                     2          0
Users contacted                                  51          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue         1,525      5,169
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              963      3,759
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        938      2,752
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               57      2,417
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               234     18,159
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue            5,125     19,257
Tags merged                                      34          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            34          2
Tag synonyms created                             31          1
Tag highlight language set                        8          0
Revisions redacted                                1          0
Questions unprotected                             2          0
Questions reopened                              716         34
Questions protected                              18        120
Questions migrated                              334         23
Questions merged                                 26          0
Questions flagged⁴                                9      3,152
Questions closed                              8,834      2,261
Question flags handled⁴                       1,342      1,819
Posts unlocked                                   10         73
Posts undeleted                                  71        509
Posts locked                                     51        581
Posts deleted⁵                                2,047     21,399
Posts bumped                                      0      8,733
Escalations to the CM team                        6          0
Comments undeleted                              129          0
Comments flagged                                  9      4,794
Comments deleted⁶                             3,596     10,518
Comment flags handled                         1,726      3,077
Bounties canceled                                16          0
Answers flagged                                  29      3,033
Answer flags handled                          2,735        327
All comments on a post moved to chat             29          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Can anyone shed light on the tantalizing-intriguing difference between "users destroyed" and "users deleted"? Both have a rather *final* sound...

Comment: Here you go, @Stephan: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user

Comment: How can non-diamond users handle comment flags?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen One way is [If a comment with zero votes and no trigger keywords (see below) is flagged by three users, it will be automatically deleted.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/215590).